# VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding descriptorCount == 0 vs not specifying the entry?

Tags: vulkan

When you create a `VkDescriptorSetLayout` you specify a set of `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`s.

```cpp
typedef struct VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding {
    uint32_t binding;
    VkDescriptorType descriptorType;
    uint32_t descriptorCount;
    VkShaderStageFlags stageFlags;
    const VkSampler* pImmutableSamplers;
} VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding;
```

This is what the spec say about `descriptorCount` being zero:

> If descriptorCount is zero this binding entry is reserved and the
> resource must not be accessed from any stage via this binding within
> any pipeline using the set layout.

I was wondering if there is any difference between setting the `descriptorCount` of a binding to zero, vs not specifying the binding at all.

For example:

```cpp
const VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding bindings[] = {
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding {
        .binding = 0,
        ...
        descriptorCount = 1,
        ...
    },
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding {
        .binding = 1,
        ...
        descriptorCount = 0,
        ...
    }, 
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding {
        .binding = 2,
        ...
        descriptorCount = 1,
        ...
    }
};

// ---------------------------------------------------

const VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding bindings[] = {
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding {
        .binding = 0,
        ...
        descriptorCount = 1,
        ...
    },
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding {
        .binding = 2,
        ...
        descriptorCount = 1,
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is any difference between setting the descriptorCount of a binding to zero, vs not specifying the binding at all.

No.

Below the descriptions of all the struct members is the following comment:

> *The above layout definition allows the descriptor bindings to be specified sparsely such that not all binding numbers between 0 and the maximum binding number need to be specified in the pBindings array. Bindings that are not specified have a descriptorCount and stageFlags of zero, and the value of descriptorType is undefined.* However, all binding numbers between 0 and the maximum binding number in the VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo::pBindings array **may** consume memory in the descriptor set layout even if not all descriptor bindings are used, though it **should** not consume additional memory from the descriptor pool.

https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap14.html#VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230610194542/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap14.html#VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding)</sub>